# Cordova Volume Slider doesn’t work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using the cordova media plugin together with the Ionic framework in order to control the volume of an audio slider.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="list list-inset" ng-controller="AudioCtrl">

    <div class="item item-divider">Audio</div>
    <div class="item">
        <audio src="media/audio.wav" preload="auto" controls id="audioSource">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    </div>

    <div class="item item-divider text-center">
        <h3>Current volume: {{ slider.volume }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="item range">
        <i class="icon ion-volume-low"></i>
        <input type="range" name="slider.volume" ng-model="slider.volume" ng-init="slider.volume=50" ng-click="setVolume()">
        <i class="icon ion-volume-high"></i>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
.controller('AudioCtrl', function($scope) {
    var audioSrc = document.getElementById("audioSource");
    audioSrc.volume = 0.5;
    $scope.setVolume = function() {
        audioSrc.volume = ($scope.slider.volume) / 100;
    }
})
```

This works in the browser but not on actual mobile devices, nothing happens there when I move the slider. I checked [the official docs](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/media/) but I can't see why it isn't working. Of course I added all dependencies in the config files etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to set the volume on the device? if so the method signature is: `.setVolume(float valueInZeroToOneRange);`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was a problem with Angulars `ng-click` which simply doesn't work on input elements. Instead, use `ng-change`.

Change this:

```
<div class="item range">
    <input type="range" ng-click="setVolume()">
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="item range">
    <input type="range" ng-change="setVolume()">
</div>
```